# How to create and call async version of caching GetOrSet method?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asynchronous, delegates

I am trying to create an `async` version of a low level caching service.

The standard non-async version is like this:

```
public class ApplicationCachingService : IApplicationCacheService
{
    public T GetOrSet<T>(string cacheKey, Func<T> getDataCallback) 
        where T : class
    {
        T data = HttpContext.Current.Application[cacheKey] as T;
        if (data == null)
        {
            data = getDataCallback();
            HttpContext.Current.Application[cacheKey] = data;
        }
        return data;
    }


    public void ClearCache(string cacheKey)
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Application[cacheKey] = null;
    }
}
```

And I am adding the following method.

```
    public async Task<T> GetOrSetAsync<T>(string cacheKey, Task<Func<T>> getDataCallback) 
        where T : class
    {
        T data = HttpContext.Current.Application[cacheKey] as T;
        if (data == null)
        {
            Func<Task<Func<T>>> myFunc = async () => await getDataCallback;
            var funcResult = await myFunc();
            data = funcResult();
            HttpContext.Current.Application[cacheKey] = data;
        }
        return data;
    }
```

**Question 1 - Is this a correct way to do it?**

I'm not sure if I need to create the `funcResult` variable, or if there is a more concise way to do it. For example, this line looks like it might be needlessly complex `Func<Task<Func<T>>> myFunc = async () => await getDataCallback;`

The above is based on pure code fudging, as delegate wise I'm a total noob.

**Question 2 - How should I call it?**

I am using this code for the standard non-async version:

```
var items = cachingService.GetOrSet<IList<BlogPostDataModel>>(
    "BlogPostsIndex",
    () => repository.GetAll<BlogPostDataModel>()
    );
```

And I am using this code for the async version:

```
var items = await cachingService.GetOrSetAsync<IList<BlogPostDataModel>>(
    "BlogPostsIndex",
    () => await repository.GetAllAsync<BlogPostDataModel>()
);
```

But the async version gives me `cannot convert lambda expression to type Task<Func<IList<BlogPostDataModel>>>' because it is not a delegate type`

---

**Final Working Example**

CodeFuller was so helpful in his answer, after reading it I got it to work straightaway. Here is the completed working code:

```
public interface IApplicationCacheService
{
    T GetOrSet<T>(string cacheKey, Func<T> getDataCallback) where T : class;
    Task<T> GetOrSetAsync<T>(string cacheKey, Func<Task<T>> getDataCallback) where T : class;
}


public class ApplicationCachingService : IApplicationCacheService
{
    public T GetOrSet<T>(string cacheKey, Func<T> getDataCallback) 
        where T : class
    {
        T data = HttpContext.Current.Application[cacheKey] as T;
        if (data == null)
        {
            data = getDataCallback();
            HttpContext.Current.Application[cacheKey] = data;
        }
        return data;
    }


    public async Task<T> GetOrSetAsync<T>(string cacheKey, Func<Task<T>> getDataCallback) 
        where T : class
    {
        T data = HttpContext.Current.Application[cacheKey] as T;
        if (data == null)
        {
            data = await getDataCallback();
            HttpContext.Current.Application[cacheKey] = data;
        }
        return data;
    }


    public void ClearCache(string cacheKey)
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Application[cacheKey] = null;
    }
}
```

Called like this:

```
var items = await cachingService.GetOrSetAsync(
    cacheKey,
    () => repository.GetAllAsync<BlogPostDataModel>()
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getDataCallback` has type of `Task<Func<T>>`. I believe (and judging by call of `GetOrSetAsync` method) you intention is not to have `Task` that will return `Func<T>` but to pass an asynchronous value factory, i.e. `Func<Task<T>>`.

So the first step is to change declaration of `GetOrSetAsync<T>`:

In `IApplicationCacheService` interface:

```
Task<T> GetOrSetAsync<T>(string cacheKey, Func<Task<T>> getDataCallback) where T : class;
```

and in `ApplicationCachingService` class:

```
public async Task<T> GetOrSetAsync<T>(string cacheKey, Func<Task<T>> getDataCallback) where T : class
```

Now you could just call `await getDataCallback()` to get the value from callback:

```
public async Task<T> GetOrSetAsync<T>(string cacheKey, Func<Task<T>> getDataCallback) where T : class
{
    T data = HttpContext.Current.Application[cacheKey] as T;
    if (data == null)
    {
        data = await getDataCallback();
        HttpContext.Current.Application[cacheKey] = data;
    }
    return data;
}
```

Now let's fix the call to `GetOrSetAsync`. If repository method `GetAllAsync` is declared as:

```
Task<IList<T>> GetAllAsync<T>() where T : class;
```

then here is a lambda that you should pass to `IApplicationCacheService.GetOrSetAsync`:

```
() => repository.GetAllAsync<BlogPostDataModel>()
```

because `GetAllAsync<BlogPostDataModel>()` returns `Task<IList<BlogPostDataModel>>` and lambda `() => repository.GetAllAsync<BlogPostDataModel>()` has the type of `Func<Task<IList<BlogPostDataModel>>>` which is exact type expected by `IApplicationCacheService.GetOrSetAsync<IList<BlogPostDataModel>>()`.

And you should not call `await` on `GetAllAsync()` in the lambda. `await` will be called inside `ApplicationCachingService.GetAllAsync()` on task returned by `getDataCallback`.

So here is the correct call of `cachingService.GetOrSetAsync`:

```
var items = await cachingService.GetOrSetAsync<IList<BlogPostDataModel>>(
    "BlogPostsIndex",
    () => repository.GetAllAsync<BlogPostDataModel>()
);
```

Comment: That is exactly the info I needed to make sense of it. Insanely helpful, thank you so much!